# Static Resource is removed when back navigation is clicked

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

looking for your can help!

I've used my own header and footer static resources which can be referenced to throughout my app. But when I use the default navigation, the resources are removed and the page loads without the header and footer.

Any ideas?

```
Back method in any content page:

 public void BackButtonHeader_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) //async
        {
            App.NavigationPage.Navigation.PopAsync();
        }

**App.xaml:**

      <!--Reference to Header class-->
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="HeaderReference" >
            <StackLayout>

                <ContentView Content="{TemplateBinding HeaderContent}" />
            </StackLayout>
        </ControlTemplate>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="HomeHeaderReference" >
            <StackLayout>
                <ContentView Content="{TemplateBinding HomeHeaderContent}" />
            </StackLayout>
        </ControlTemplate>


<ContentView x:Key="Header">
            <StackLayout>
                <Grid VerticalOptions="Start">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height= "50" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
                        <RowDefinition Height= "*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height= "*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions >

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width= "20" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width = "*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="25"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width= "10" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions >

                    <Image Source = "btnBack.png" x:Name="btnBack" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,-20,0,0" >
                        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="BackButtonHeader_Clicked" />
                        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Image>

                    <Image Source = "logosmallw.png" x:Name="logo" HeightRequest="80"  Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>

                    <Image Source = "btnSearch.png" x:Name="btnSearch" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,-20,0,0">
                        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="searchFoodPage"></TapGestureRecognizer>
                        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Image>
                </Grid>

                <ContentPresenter VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"></ContentPresenter>

            </StackLayout>
        </ContentView>

**myHeader cs:**

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace myApp
{

    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]

    public partial class myHeader : ContentView
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty HomeHeaderContentProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(HomeHeaderContent),
            typeof(View), typeof(myHeader));

        public View HomeHeaderContent
        {
            get { return (View)GetValue(HomeHeaderContentProperty); }
            set { SetValue(HomeHeaderContentProperty, value); }
        }

        public myHeader()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}


**myHeaderNavigation cs:**

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace myApp
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class myHeaderNavigation : ContentView
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty HeaderContentProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(HeaderContent),
            typeof(View), typeof(myHeaderNavigation));

        public View HeaderContent
        {
            get { return (View)GetValue(HeaderContentProperty); }
            set { SetValue(HeaderContentProperty, value); }
        }

        public myHeaderNavigation()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}

**Content Page - Navigation:**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="myApp.myReport"
    NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
    >

    <StackLayout>
         <local:myHeaderNavigation
            HeaderContent="{StaticResource Header}"
            ControlTemplate="{StaticResource HeaderReference}" />

        <local:myFooter
                            FooterContent="{StaticResource Footer}" 
                            ControlTemplate="{StaticResource FooterReference}" />
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Source: https://lukealderton.com/blog/posts/2017/january/replacing-the-xamarin-headernavigation-bar-with-a-custom-viewtemplate/

Source: https://wolfprogrammer.com/2016/09/02/creating-a-hamburger-menu-in-xamarin-forms/

Comment: How do you set the ControlTemplat? For all the pages? And is the `BackButtonHeader` same with `OnBackButtonPressed` in the blog? According to the blog, i made a code sample to test. Navigate from page 10 to page 9 and then tap the image to back to the page 10. Please check my screenshot: https://imgur.com/yDOIpy7

Comment: Apologies for the delay, I also customised the navigation for my hamburger menu, see additional examples and source attached as I'm not using the standard pop/push functionality. Hope you can help!

Comment: I can't tell from the code you've posted, what is on the nav stack, hence what `Navigation.PopAsync` will show. Please show 1) the outermost container. Is this a Shell app? A ContentPage? What? 2) Your control template. Don't need it all, just enough to see the technique. 3) a minimal first page, that includes (references) the header and footer or the control template.  4) the code that navigates from first page to second page.

Comment: Hi @ToolmakerSteve  - Please see edits, this is a Xamarin project, I posted the outmost files of the App.xaml and Content pages. I've used the page navigation example shown first within all content page, hope that helps :)

Comment: sorry, the page navigation example at what url?